# How to count size of a directory using os.walk() python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, azure, databricks

How to count size of a directory using `os.walk()` python?

I could get all the root files using below code-

```
root = "/dbfs/mnt/datalake/Persistent/External/"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        print (os.path.join(path, name))
```

But I need total directory size of "External". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
import os
size=0
root = "/dbfs/mnt/datalake/Persistent/External/"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        size+=os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path, name))

print(size)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's what I wanted. And---to convert this size into MB do I just divide with 1024 ?

Comment: No, you divide it by (1024*1024) to get MB. Only dividing by 1024 will give you KB.